# Title Bar with a picture in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

We have the standard Sharepoint site for our group at work and was wondering if we could add into the title bar where our group name is (like to the right of it), or above the announcements/calender widgets a

1. picture that resembles our group
2. and a mission statement right next to it

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the appropriate permissions, you can edit the page (More likely the master page) for the site using SharePoint Designer which is free from Microsoft.  If you upload the image you want to a document library you can use that url for the img src.

- [SharePoint Designer 2010](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/sharepoint-designer.aspx)
- [SharePoint Designer 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=baa3ad86-bfc1-4bd4-9812-d9e710d44f42&displaylang=en)

But a simpler solution would be to edit the page, add a new web part and choose the **Content Editor Web Part** where you can put your mission statement and an image (that you previously uploaded to a document library).

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which version of SharePoint you are using, but changing the logo of a site hasn't changed much since the 2003 version. Office.Microsoft.com shows [the user perspective of changing a logo](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/changing-portal-site-properties-and-site-creation-settings-HA001160351.aspx). You could change the same setting through the API.